# Will Tesla steer if autopilot is engaged but your hand are on the wheel? If so how much force is required to overcome autosteer?

Tags: steering, electric-vehicle, tesla

I don't own a Tesla but I have read a lot about them. I know that there is an autosteer feature that allows the car to steer for you, but I also know that you need to constantly put your hands on the wheel in order for it not to leave autosteer mode. My question is this: Will the Tesla steer for you while your hands are resting on the wheel, and if so how much force do you need to apply to counter its attempts to steer? Obviously you would want to be able to steer your car if you disagreed with autopilot, but you wouldn't want the weight of your resting hands to prevent autosteer from working if you want it to steer for you.

Comment: Take one for a test drive...

Comment: Of course it will since they suggest you keep your hands on the steering wheel when auto steer is on. It will always respond to driver input no matter what.

Comment: @Moab, so are you saying that it will autosteer while your hands are on the wheel or are you saying that it will respond to any (even the slightest) driver input? It can't really be both...

Comment: Believe it or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With your hands on the wheel, you will be able to feel the wheel turning as the autosteer applies steering force.  If you try to gently turn the wheel yourself, it will apply an opposite force in order to keep you going in the direction it wants.  If you turn the wheel harder, it senses this, and cancels the autosteering on the assumption you want to take over.

It's not the weight of your hands, so much as it is the extra force it supplies to make your hands turn with the wheel, that it is measuring.  In fact, with both hands on the wheel and all the turning force perfectly balanced out, it sometimes doesn't even know you are holding it.  You sometimes have to supply small inputs to assure it you are there.

Comment: It must be said that the software controlling all this is constantly being updated, and so the exact circumstances are subject to change.

Comment: To avoid the "nag" where it asks you to hold onto the wheel, you do indeed need to constantly apply a little bit of torque. I keep one hand with a light grip around the 4 o'clock position using the weight of my arm pulling slightly down.

There is definitely a certain amount it will let you move the wheel back and forth while fighting you. You can predict where it will "pop" and release control to you by how much force feedback it is fighting you with.